# Access denied for user sugar/modules/Accounts/Account.php on line 275

Tags: php, mysql, sugarcrm

I am installing [Inventory Items](http://www.sugarforge.org/projects/inventory-items) module in Sugar CRM and have the same issue as mentioned [here](http://forums.sugarcrm.com/f115/message-after-install-opensales-warning-access-denied-user-odbc-localhost-60980/) I figured out that maybe module which I am using is pretty old and its not creating the database properly. Any help ?

Comment: Post the error messages you are receiving.

Comment: you need to read up on granting mysql permissions

Comment: lmgtfy: [link]http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/grant.html

Comment: This is the error message I am getting 
`mysql_query() [function.mysql-query]: Access denied for user 'starsdom'@'localhost' (using password: NO) in /home/starsdom/public_html/shamuzzi.ae/sugar/modules/Accounts/Account.php on line 275`

Answer (score 1):

Change line no `275 to 279` in `modules/Accounts/Account.php` to

```
if( $result = $this->db->query( $sql ) )
{
  $row = $this->db->fetchByAssoc( $result );
  $this->square_feet = $row['SUM(square_footage)']; 
}
```

The module is replacing the file `modules/Accounts/Account.php` which is not a good idea as an upgraded version of SugarCRM would have different code. If you have taken a backup before installing this module, compare your backup file and the present file.

Comment: thanks! I figured it out and did the same as you suggested :)